# re.findall() finds results on the first run but not the second

Tags: python, regex

I'm running a quick rtt comparison with ping on a list of urls. I want to extract the ip so I can run a whois and get the geographical location. What happens when I run this on a list of urls starting specifically with google.com and facebook.com is that an ip is matched by regex for google, but not facebook even though the output for both from ping is identically formatted. The code below gives better idea of what's going on.

```
urls = ["google.com", "facebook.com"]
ip_regex = re.compile('[1-9]+\\.[1-9]+\\.[1-9]+\\.[1-9]+')
time_regex = re.compile(' [\.1-9]+/.*/.*/.* ms') 

for url in urls:
    output = ""
    print url

    ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "3", url], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    while ping.poll() == None:
        output += ping.stdout.read()

    output += ping.stdout.read()

    #DEBUG
    print "OUTPUT"
    print output

    ip = ip_regex.findall(output)
    print ip

    ip = ip[0]

    times = time_regex.findall(output)

    print times

    os.system('whois ' + ip + ' | egrep "Country|StateProv|City"')
```

Does the ip_regex fail on facebook (#2) for anyone else? Why?

Comment: you might want to use python raw strings with regular expressions eg:ip_regex = re.compile( r'[1-9]+\.[1-9]+\.[1-9]+\.[1-9]+'), in this way you do not have to escape backslashes in the expression, this makes the regex much easier to read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are zeroes in facebook's IP. `1-9` does not include zero.

While we're at it, use raw strings for regexes:

```
r'[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
```

Use the `\d` class for matching digits:

```
r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+'
```

Don't forget to fix the other regex:

```
r' [\.0-9]+/.*/.*/.* ms'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex for finding an IP address is b0rked.  Here is a better one:

```
ip_pattern = r'(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){3}'
```

Comment: Why are engineers so fascinated with over-engineering regexes to make them "right"?

Comment: That's a pretty harsh downvote ..  it's certainly no worse than the naive regex in the other answer which accepts `999999.09.000.999` as an ip address.

Comment: I agree, the downvote is unwarranted, but I'm not sure about your definition of "better". I guess one that works is better than one that's broken, but wouldn't it make more sense to just locate patterns that are "probably IP's" using regex and then use python to validate them?

Comment: Respectfully disagree.. if I'm going to use a regex in the first place, I would prefer a precise/exact one than a mixture of regex and some extra validation code.  Less moving parts and all that.  And there's nothing "probably" about it, `192.168.0.256` simply _can't_ be an IPv4 address.

Comment: As this was a quick throwaway script using input with a pretty well-defined format, I wasn't going for precision, just speed and results. So a shorter, easier-to-read regex is preferable to a "correct" one in this case.

Comment: @wim: fewer moving parts is a good goal, but so is simplicity.  This regex is a nightmare, and I can't tell by looking at it whether it's right or not.  Plus, any IP address I find will have to be checked for validity anyway.  Is 1.2.3.4 a real address?  The regex can't figure it out, so there will be another step anyway.